# Meteor - Mysql (Integration between LAMP and Meteor.JS) cross platform

Tags: mysql, meteor, cross-domain, cross-platform, single-sign-on

I have an existing application based in LAMP and now I am looking to develop a new module of the existing system in Meteor.JS (Only New Module, keeping the existing system as it is)

I know that Mysql is not officially supported till now in Meteor. I have gathered some knowledge that, using a package [numtel:mysql](https://atmospherejs.com/numtel/mysql), we may get support for mysql, but I feel that is also limited.

Now, my question is: I have one project built on a LAMP stack, and I wanted to develop a new module for this in Meteor using the same Mysql database, as its contains existing records. (I know that I have to do some workaround for sign-in and authentication between two, and that I have to take care too.

But I just wanted to know, Is it possible to use the existing system (Mysql database) and what are the possibilities of creating a new module in Meteor. Can someone put shed light into this scenario?

Also, can someone suggest to me how to do single sign-on between these two different applications (LAMP and Meteor)

What are the steps that I should take in order to achieve this?

Comment: You should give details about what (if anything) you’ve actually tried so far, and any code you have that might at least have experimented with at this point. And consider refining your question those those details, or submitting a more-detailed question later after you’ve tried some thing. Otherwise, this question is at high risk of getting flagged as “too broad” and downvoted and deleted.

Comment: @sideshowbarker - I understand what you mean and you are correct at your point, Actually why I asked this question because I just wanted to get some idea if someone has already done this before and if someone can guide me how to go ahead in this kind of scenario. before putting this question I have done some study and read some articles and went through some forums, I mean I have not started any coding yet as I don't know the best way to achieve this. if some one can give me some idea on this - How to use existing Mysql Database which is used in exsiting LAMP App with a new module in Meteor.